# Is there a corresponding way to extract certification info from .exe file in RING0

Tags: driver

As we know, in RING3, we could use CryptQueryObject. In driver, is there a way to get the certification information? 
I tried to find it from the export symbols of ntosknel.exe, but I didn't make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so trivial )
There two types of signed images: with embedded signature and catalog signed. For first category you must do follow:

1) Extract signature and some info from PE image. Format is documented here http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/Authenticode_PE.mspx

Basically you need to extract IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY directory and retrive, needed for kernel crypto api, information.

2) Verify signature with kernel mode crypto api (http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/Authenticode_PE.mspx), basically BCryptVerifySignature function
This api avaiable from Vista. For XP there are FIPS driver as i remember.

I don't know any ways to check catalog signed executables from KM, because we need to find signature somewhere in catalog and i don`t know how.

From another point of view this capability are not supported by MS and thats way we need to transfer this feature to user mode helper application with some caching of information in kernel mode for perfomance. Driver will ask helper application to check signature of pe image (by help of inverted call for example) if not found this info in cache.